# Why is the genitive case necessary/unecessary in the examples below?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, possessives, possessive-s-vs-of

I speak English as a second language, and I ran into something this week that I couldn't explain, even though I could understand its meaning. While reading an artcle entitled "More people now subscribe to Netflix than cable TV in the US" I read the following sentences along it:

> "(...) the number of US **Netflix subscribers** overtook the number (...)"
>
> "(...) **Netflix's gain** isn't necessarily cable's loss"
>
> "(...) **Netflix's milestone** is yet another sign (...)"

My question is: Why is there no genitive case for "Netflix subscribers", but the other two examples make use of it?

Does the noun "Netflix" work as an adjective for the noun "subscribers"? If so, why doesn't it apply to the other two examples?

Comment: There's no genitive suffix on the noun phrase _subscribers_ in the first sentence because that noun phrase is the object of the preposition _of_, which means the same (more or less) as the genitive, and is rarely used together with it (except in idioms like _a friend of Bill's_). Incidentally, note that the genitive of _Netflix_, which comes from a plural _flicks_, is _Netflix's_, with an apostrophe-S suffix instead of just an apostrophe like a plural would get.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think the question has more to do with when do we use *Walmart's customers* and when do we use *Walmart customers*. It comes down to where the focus lies. Target is stealing Walmart's customers. Sears customers are more loyal than Gap customers. I have avoided JCPenney, which is still widely called Penney's, and Macy's, and Tiffany's, which are notoriously awkward.

Comment: It's not a simple matter. _Target is stealing Walmart('s) customers_ (either is OK), but *_Target is stealing Walmart thunder_ (the idiom requires genitive). The Business Genitive (I grew up with _Kroger's, A & P's,_ even _Piggly Wiggly's_) can be applied to any proper name associated with a business, especially a large-scale retail business (like _Field's, Macy's,_ or _Gimbel's_) so that it's frequently on people's lips.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I would have said that in the first sentence, "Netflix" operates as a noun modifying the word "subscriber," just as it does in the phrase "Netflix subscription." Note phrases like "magazine subscribers," "television viewers," and "radio listeners" which would never have the first word in possessive form.